# Locale language for Javascript in Magento

Tags: magento

We can config in `Magento` to set locale language and using function `$this->__(string $test)` to translate.

How about this feature but for `javascript`? For example, when I use `validation.js` and when getting some errors it will show the message with the locale language which I set.

The validation.js file is located at: `src/js/prototype/prototype.js`

In inside the file we will see something:

```
Validation.addAllThese([
    ['validate-select', 'Please select an option.', function(v) {
                return ((v != "none") && (v != null) && (v.length != 0));
            }],
    ['required-entry', 'This is a required field.', function(v) {
                return !Validation.get('IsEmpty').test(v);
            }],
    ['validate-number', 'Please enter a valid number in this field.', function(v) {
                return Validation.get('IsEmpty').test(v) || (!isNaN(parseNumber(v)) && !/^\s+$/.test(parseNumber(v)));
            }]
]
```

So, how could I translate the messages `This is a required field.`,`Please select an option.`?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I'm not sure if that's what you're asking, but the translations of th javascript messages are set in **app/code/Core/Mage/Core/Helper/Js.php** -> `_getTranslateData()` and is called in app/design/*package*/ *theme*/template/page/html/head.phtml `<?php echo $this->helper('core/js')->getTranslatorScript() ?>`

I've just need that myself, let me refrase:

1. in the phtml you add the strings you need to translate:

   ```
   <script type="text/javascript">
       //<![CDATA[
           Translator.add('String to translate', '<?php echo $this->__('String to translate'); ?>');
       //]]>
   </script>
   ```
2. in your javascript file, use:

   ```
   Translator.translate('String to translate');
   ```
3. now you can use your csv translations files

Comment: OK, I will updated my question to make more clear and try your suggestion. Thanks in advanced.

Comment: You have opened my eyes, so, can you give me more sign which could make me more clear to resolve this?

Comment: you need to add the string you want to translate in the language package

Comment: Really? Even if this is javascript and not php?

Comment: This is not the "right" way to do this. Plese check my answer

Answer (score 1):

The correct method to add Javascript translations and avoid mixing PHP and JS is to add a jstranslator.xml file in your module.

The content of the file should be something like this:

```xml
<jstranslator>
    <my-message translate="message" module="mymodule">
        <message>My Original Message in Base Language</message>
    </my-message>
</jstranslator>
```

Then simple use yout own module's translation csv files to translate those strings.

Its worth mentioning that if you intend to translate core validation massages, those are already located in Mage_Core.csv translation file. You should create the corresponding translation file for your locale or customize the translations via the translate.csv file in your theme as usual.